# How to unselect any selected record in an infragistics XamDataGrid?

Tags: xamdatagrid

I have a `XamDataGrid` with `XamComboEditor` as its `CellValuePresenter`.

I have written a handler for `XamComboEditor SelectionChanged` event (`XamComboSelectionChanged`) that updates my collection as per selected item.

When I apply filter to the `XamDataGrid` from its header, it triggers `XamComboSelectionChanged` event handler somehow and the value from `XamDataGrid.ActiveRecord` gets updated due this event handler. I want to avoid this.

This problem does not occur if I don't click on any record. i.e. `XamDataGrid.ActiveRecord` is `null`.
If there is any way I can unselect the selected row my problem would be solved.

I have tried setting `XamDataGrid.ActiveRecord = null` in `RecordFilterChanged` event of `XamDataGrid` didn't work.

`XamDataGrid.ActiveRecord.IsActive = false` didn't work.

`XamDataGrid.ActiveRecord.IsSelected = fals` didn't work.

Also I tried to update dependency property but I can only set it to any other record only which still causes same issue:
`xamDataGrid.SetValue(XamDataGrid.ActiveRecordProperty, xamDataGrid.Records[0]);`  -- can't set anything out of index here.

Please help

Thanks